# I want to schedule fcm notification for specific user when he add a task to database, flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Actually what I am working on a to-do task manager app. Currently I am adding tasks to cloud Firestore after as a new document. I want to send notification to user at the time user scheduled to do that work. I am so confused. It can be lots of tasks from a single user. And the the notification tone has to be selected by user itself.

Please help me in this..

Thanks you!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388542/how-to-send-fcm-push-notification-dynamically/68388682#68388682) maybe useful. It uses Cloud Tasks to schedule tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll need:

A database where you keep the notification payload, user FCM token, and the time they are to be sent.

A schedule Cloud Function that runs every day or every hour based on the granularity of the task.

Now, when the Cloud Function gets triggered, it:

- Runs a query against the database for notifications that are scheduled to be sent before the current time
- Loops over the results send each notification in turn.
- You can now delete the database entry if you want to.

Furthermore, if you want to reduce the number of cloud function triggers, you have a combination of the FCM and an alarm manager to show a notification after a delay (feasible in flutter through local notifications too). this way you can send the payload at a particular time of the day and deploy it at any time locally.

Not sure how optimized this is, looking for better ways!