# Run firebase schedule function one time and delete it once it run(cancel the recurrence)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using the Firebase service for the project. We have a requirement that a user can schedule tasks for specific times. For example Jan 30th at 2 PM, Feb 2nd at 3 PM, and N. On the particular date and time, the scheduler must fire up and do the logic and have to **delete without recurrence.** To achieve this, I have explored the firebase services and found firebase scheduler functions that can be scheduled with unix-corn string format.

So each schedule I am creating a new scheduler function with every `onWrite` function event. So there will be a couple of scheduler function trigger for completing specific jobs. For example, one of the scheduler functions will trigger on Jan 30th at 2 PM and complete the task and have to **delete that Jan at 2 PM scheduler function** to prevent recurrence in the future.

I can do scheduling and all but couldn't find a way to delete that particular function other than the shell command `firebase functions:delete scheduledFunction`. Is there any way to delete the schedule function programmatically?

I have found an option to [delete the pub-sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-delete-topic#pubsub_delete_topic-nodejs) topic. Will pub-sub topic delete do a complete delete of the schedule function? also, it seems it's not part of the firebase admin SDK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) are ideal for creating such dynamic schedules. When a user schedules a task, you can add a Cloud Task that'll call your Cloud Function (or any API) at the given time *once*.

Also checkout:

1. [Enqueue Functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions)
2. [How to send FCM push notification dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388542/how-to-send-fcm-push-notification-dynamically/68388682#68388682)

   (Explains how a Cloud function can be called at given schedule and frequency)

Comment: Thank you. But cloud task has the limitation that 30 days is the maximum amount of time in the future that a task can be scheduled. (https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas). My requirement is the user can schedule to any date.

Comment: @FahryMohammed I would assume you are storing those tasks in some database? Here a scheduled cloud function that runs once a day or so can be helpful to create tasks for upto next 30 days?

Comment: Thank you @Dharmaraj. Finally, I have utilized Cloud Tasks.